# Bartender software Database Connection Menu not available

Tags: excel, database, menu, connection, bartender

I am using **Bartender** software version 2016, software comes along with TSC pro Barcode Printer.

**Details...**
Program:    TSC Special Edition BarTender 2016 R7
License:    UltraLite
Version:    11.0.7.3146 (32-bit)
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise x64 build 18363

I want to print barcode labels for specific numbers from **MS Excel** file.
but the **"Database Connection Setup Menu"** that should be in File menu is not available.

How can I print?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available in the UltraLite version of BarTender. You need a basic edition or higher!